# Assembly Dynamic memory allocation x86

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

i am trying to allocate 50 bytes through the calloc macro in my String query proc. The issue is i'm not sure how to do that, and for sure the way i am attempting to do it is wrong.  i tried passing 50 into the EAX register, and then calling the calloc macro. my program complies but thats it. so my question is how do properly use these procedures? do i play with the registers by moving values into the registers? and once i get back the allocated space where does that space live in? the registers? i can't use any global variables, that is the point of this exercise. Thanks much for any help.

```
    INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

    ; Macro to ease the use of alloc procedure 

    mAlloc      Macro      Value
    Push        offset  value
    Call        ALLOC
    endM

   ;Macro to ease the use of memFree
   free       Macro      value 
   push       offset     value 
   Call       memFree
   endM


   ; Macro to ease the use of the alloc procedure, for character data
   cAlloc      Macro     Value
   mov         eax, sizeof BYTE
   imul        eax, Value  

   Push      eax
   Call      alloc
   endM

   ;Macro to ease the use of of the alloc procedure for integer Data
   iAlloc      Macro     Value
   mov         eax, sizeof WORD
   imul        eax, Value 

   Push      eax 
   Call      mAlloc
   endM

   ;Macro to ease the use of the alloc for long interger DATA 
   lAlloc      Macro      Value
   mov         eax, sizeof DWORD
   imul        eax, Value 

   Push       OFFSET   value
   Call       mAlloc
   endM

   ;Macro for string query 
   STRQRYM    Macro      value
   Push       OFFSET value
   Call       strQry
   ENDM

   .data
   HeapHandle TEXTEQU <[EBP - 4]>
   Prompt    Byte "Please enter your name: ", 0
   Message   Byte "the name you entered is: ", 0


   .code
   ALLOC       PROC
   push        EBP
   MOV         EBP, ESP
   SUB         ESP, 4

   INVOKE      GetprocessHeap
   ;MOV        HeapHandle, EAX
   INVOKE      HeapAlloc, HeapHandle, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,[EBP + 8]

   ADD         ESP, 4
   POP         EBP
   RET         4
   ALLOC       ENDP

   memFree     PROC
   push        ebp
   mov         ebp, esp

   INVOKE      GetProcessHeap
   ; mov heap handle to eax? 
   Invoke       HeapFree, EAX, 0, [EBP + 8]

   pop         ebp
   RET         4
   memFree     ENDP

   strQry      PROC
   Push        EBP
   Mov         EBP, ESP

   Push        EDX
   push        ECX

   ;print string 
   Mov         EDX, [EBP + 8]
   Call        writeString

   ; create byte and push 50 characters into a variable 
   Mov         ECX, 50  

   mov         eax, 50
   calloc      eax 
   Call        readString


     Pop         ECX
     Pop         EDX
     Pop         EBP

     Ret         4



      strQry      ENDP

      MAIN        PROC

      ;test strQRY allocate 50 bytes 
    ; MEM should free memory at adress and send an indication back 
    that it has happend
     ;test each proc and Macro approrpiately (display)

     STRQRYM     prompt


      EXIT
      Main ENDP
      END Main
```

Comment: `calloc eax` is going to be a surprise.

Comment: Why not `imul eax, Value, sizeof x`?  Or require it to be a register so you can use `lea eax, [Value * sizeof x]` instead of using a multiply instruction with a power-of-2 size.

Answer (score 1):

```
   ; Macro to ease the use of the alloc procedure, for character data
   cAlloc      Macro     Value
   mov         eax, sizeof BYTE
   imul        eax, Value  

   Push      eax
   Call      alloc
   endM
```

In conjunction with usage:

```
calloc      eax
```

Will produce code:

```
   mov       eax, 1
   imul      eax, eax  ; eax = 1
   push      eax
   call      alloc
```

... probably not, what you expected, rather use `edx` for input ... or stop using macros and rather turn them into regular subroutines, then `call` them (tends to be easier to read + debug, macros change output machine code from source a lot, and there's no benefit except unmeasurable fraction of performance, which is pointless in this case, as the dynamic allocation is already very slow operation, one additional `call` will not break it).

Also what's so bad about:

```
    push 50
    call alloc
```

That it needs another macro like `cAlloc`?

---

About *"not allowed to use globals"*.

Then allocate some space on stack, like `sub esp,100h` to have 256 bytes of space from `esp+0` to `esp+255` (if you did set up stack frame into `ebp` in common way, and you did `sub esp,100h` after that, then the local reserved space is at `ebp-100h .. ebp-1h`.

The macro `HeapHandle` even suggest such usage, although I would remove that and write the `[ebp-4]` in code rather, the string "`HeapHandle`" makes it hard for source reader to see what is the actual resulting machine code. I generally frown on macro usage in assembly, it's IMO very bad practice. Usually the only legitimate assembly usage is for performance programming, where you write tiny bit of performance focused code in assembly, being called from high level language. At that point in the tiny assembly you want it to be as straightforward as possible, macros are hiding resulting machine code from the reader, which makes review/modification lot more harder. And there's no advantage to usage of macros (if it's too long/boring to write the code in assembly w/o macros, then the choice of assembly was very likely the wrong decision and that part of code should have been written in HLPL).

EDIT: the commented out `;MOV        HeapHandle, EAX` is probably mistake too, check Irvine lib docs, how the heap handle is returned, but it is very likely in `eax`, so your next `invoke` using that `[ebp-4]` will use some random value in stack, instead of the handle value (when that `mov` is commented).

If you want to use all that macro magic, then probably don't even bother with posting original source, rather post listing file or disassembly, also use debugger with disassembly view to get better idea what you are truly doing to your computer.

And finally, if you need just 50 bytes, it may be much simpler to allocate them on the stack (just by that `sub esp,...` way). Kilobyte-kind of sizes are perfect fit for stack usage, 100+ kiB sizes are probably better for heap usage. So you can save you all that hassle with `alloc + free` for such tiny bit of memory.

Anyway, you should study + practice both, so it's still valid exercise, I just wouldn't recommend it for production, 50B-like allocations would trash the heap manager soon if done on larger scale.